# How to prevent Gitlab to create jobs on a new branch while using a changes:paths rule

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want my pipeline to create jobs only when specific paths in a repo have changes, using the rule listed below does what I need but not in the first commit to a new branch

Here is part of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have.

```
.preview-tf-plan:
  extends:
    - .terraform-plan
  environment:
    name: preview
    url: https://app.com
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      changes:
        paths:
          - ${TF_PATH}/*

preview-tf-plan-apps-folder1:
    extends:
      - .preview-tf-plan
    variables:
      TF_PATH: terraform/apps-folder1
  
  preview-tf-plan-apps-folder2:
    extends:
      - .preview-tf-plan
    variables:
      TF_PATH: terraform/apps-folder2
  
  preview-tf-plan-apps-folder3:
    extends:
      - .preview-tf-plan
    variables:
      TF_PATH: terraform/apps-folder3
  
  preview-tf-plan-apps-inf:
    extends:
      - .preview-tf-plan
    variables:
      TF_PATH: terraform/apps-folder4
```

Let me provide some context about what my pipeline does. When there's a change in one of the `apps-[key]` path a job is created with the Terraform code within that path

The problem is the following; When you create a new branch and push the first commit to that branch, the pipeline run the jobs for all the `apps-[key]` paths instead of the ones that have actual changes, ignoring the changes:paths rule. On consecutive commits to the same branch the rule works well, it creates jobs only for the paths that have modifications. What I'm trying to do is to avoid the pipeline to run the jobs for all paths on the first commit of a new branch.

I tried the [rules:changes:compare_to](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#ruleschangescompare_to) but it does the same thing

Comment: If your `rules:changes:compare_to` points to the ref from which you created the new branch (e.g., `main` branch) then this rule shouldn't evaluate true when creating the branch. Do you have other rules? Do you want to control this _just_ for some jobs, or skip the pipeline altogether when creating a new branch?

Comment: Could you please clarify the wording you're using? Is in your world creating a new file *not* a change of the file? (just asking, no preference, to better understand your question).

Comment: Hi folks, I've edited the description of the problem for better comprehension, apologies for the confusion. @sytech yes that was my assumption, I used the compare_to with the ref `preview` which is the branch I'm creating my new branches from. I want to control some jobs and overall the rule is working fine, the only problem is when I do a first commit to a NEW branch.

Comment: @hakre either create a new file or modify a file within a specific path, please see the description of the problem one more time since I added additional info for better comprehension